# jquery array passed to php gives unexpected format

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have passed an array from jquery to a php processing script through ajax post.  I noticed that my foreach iteration in php was not doing anything.  I added in a vat_dump and realized the strange results I got back for the array.  Why is there a string(x) appended to the values?  I believe this is why my loop is not running properly.

I am quite familiar with arrays in php, but as far as passing jquery ones to php and using them I have never come across something like this.

```
$('#delete').on('click', function () {

    var selected = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var data = {
      'selected': selected
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/process/p_delete.php',
        data: data,
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function (response) {

        if (response.success)
        {                                                                                               
            // show success toast
            toastr.info('Selected activities have been deleted from your account.');                        
        } 
        else
        {
            // show error toast
            toastr.error('An error has occurred. &nbsp;Please contact support.', 'Error');
        }

    });
});
```

then in php :

```
$selected = $_POST['selected'];
var_dump($selected);

// prepare the statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM logs WHERE activity_id = ? AND account_id = ?");

//loop through array and delete each selected
foreach($selected as $key)
{
    $binding = array(
    'account_id' => $_SESSION['user']['account_id'],
    'activity_id' => $key
    );

    // execute the delete
    $stmt->execute($binding);
}
```

the dump results in this :

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

Comment: this is the var_dump result styling. you can try `print_r('<pre>'); print_r($selected);` you will get your expected result. but what you are getting is perfectly okay.

"foreach iteration in php was not doing anything" its mean so database transaction have done?

Comment: You are right the print_r gives me what I expected, however, that does not explain why my db delete loop does nothing.  Unless I am really tired and not seeing a mistake there shouldn't be anything wrong with it.  Account_id is valid and activity_id's are as well... both are of type integer in the db and I have done db functions like this plenty of times just without data coming from jquery.

Comment: you are getting session data properly?

Comment: Yes, double checked... there really is nothing different than this and many others that are working perfectly fine except for the array being passed in.

Comment: can you echo the $key, $_SESSION['user']['account_id'] in the foreach loop

Comment: I posted an answer below... too tired and wasn't seeing the code straight.  I was trying to bind my parameters without specifying their binding in the prepared statement.  Partly from being tried and partly from copying the statement from another part of my code where I wasn't binding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44759/discussion-between-crack-and-user756659)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$stmt->execute(array($key, $_SESSION['user']['account_id']));
```

or use named parameters (see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). And instead of making multiple queries, it'd be better to use just one query using WHERE IN -clause.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert in PHP but I would try like this :

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var selected = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(selected);//encode array to JSON format
var data = {
  'selected': jsonObj
};
```

**PHP**

```
  $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['selected']));//decode json to array
  foreach($data as $value){
     echo $value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM logs WHERE activity_id = :activityId AND account_id = :accountId');

//loop through array and delete each selected
foreach($selected as $key)
{
    $sth->bindParam(':activityId', $_SESSION['user']['account_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(':accountId', $key, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

if you get `$_SESSION['user']['account_id']` and `$key` properly then it will work. also check pdo database connectivity and column name and table name

Answer (score 0):

doh... I guess this is what happens when I am super tired...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM logs WHERE activity_id = :activity_id AND account_id = :account_id");
```

I had copied my statement from another part of my code where I was directly inserting the values into this statement.  In this one I am binding them... therefore, the = ? is no good in this case.